# How to define the WP_QUERY class in an external php file?

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I'm trying to submit a form to a php page that contains a WP_QUERY, I need the query to read it's arguments from the submitted form using Ajax. When I load the page like this:

```
echo get_bloginfo('template_directory').'/mailform_action.php';
```

The WP_QUERY becomes undefined. And when I create a wordpress page and load that page as action="test" such that page-test.php is the page name in the theme file I get an error form the console:

> http://localhost/nafham_testing/testFailed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

What's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to include `wp_load.php` at the top of your `mailform_action.php`

Answer (score 1):

Use something like that at the top of your script :

`<?php require('/the/path/to/your/wp-blog-header.php'); ?>`

Comment: You should use wp_load.php instead of wp-blog-header.php, because wp-blog-header.php will make the page return a 404 status.